# Integrate system level settings for dark mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need your help to integrate `prefers-color-scheme` to my existing dark mode settings.

This is the JS I'm using:

```
 <script>
    const switcher = document.querySelector('#switcher');
    const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

    function setTheme(theme) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', theme);
        localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);

        const src = 'https://example.com/' + (theme === 'light' ? 'DARK-MODE-1.png' : 'LIGHT-MODE-1.png');
        switcher.setAttribute('src', src);
    }

    const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light';
    setTheme(theme);

    toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        const theme = e.currentTarget.checked ? 'dark' : 'light';
        setTheme(theme);
    });
    </script>
```

And this is the HTML where src="" takes and generates image path (for e.g. example.com/DARK-MODE-1.png) from above JS.

```
<label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
                    <span title="Click to enable/disable Dark Mode">
                        <img id="switcher" src="">
                    </span>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
                </label>
```

Now I want to use `prefers-color-scheme` to this code so when user's system is at dark mode, it automatically switches to dark mode. If user machine is in light mode, the light mode should be offered. Additionally, user should be able switch to any mode if they want.

Thanks for any help and your time!

Answer (score 0):

"Dark mode can be detected in Javascript by using window.matchMedia() to check a match for the prefers-color-scheme: dark CSS media query."

```js
let matched = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;

if(matched)
    const theme = 'dark'; //switch to dark theme
else
    const theme = 'light'; //use light theme
```

`window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: )')` accepts `dark`, `light` and `no-preference` as possible queries.

(via [usefulangle.com](https://usefulangle.com/post/318/javascript-check-dark-mode-activated))

I hope my answer helped you get closer to your desired outcome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to be work, but I'm not sure where I should add these lines in my code. Can you please share me the complete code including window.matchMedia() under <script> tags. Once again, thanks for your help.

Comment: You can put th above code in your function `setTheme`.

Comment: I am a newbie to JS, so can't figure it out. Should I add it after this line:

localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I am also kinda new to JS - I can't help then, but I can try. Does console return any error?